# 'if statement' not firing on mobile?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, mobile

This works fine on everything except for mobile. Is there a reason for this? How do I get around it?

```
$(document).ready(function()
  var my_var = 10;
  if(! my_var =="") {
    //do my code
  }
});
```

Comment: where is `my_var ` defined ?

Comment: Editing to include my_var...

Comment: I included where my_var is defined.

Comment: I've just checked [this jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/742yhvmh/) and it works fine for me on mobile.

Comment: When I change your fiddle to an alert instead, it works on most platforms, but it does not send the alert on my mobile device. I have an older android os.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (my_var) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: I want it to run when the value is not empty.

Comment: I see that you edited your answer now. That is basically the same code, but still doesn't work on android 4.4.2 stock browser.